# How do I select the following DOM object to style it?

Tags: css

I want to do this:

```
.class
{
    color: green;
}
```

On the highlighted item.

Please note, I cannot use the class ".k-in" because it's used elsewhere in this DIV. Also note that the children items are also a span element so I can't use span either.

[image]

I want to select ALL of the items that are structured the same as the highlighted item (notice that there are 4 "parent" list items in this DOM so I need to run a color green on each of the parents.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: .k- top .k-in   ???????????

Comment: Your image is not displaying.

Comment: top is only the top parent node. I need all of the nodes

Comment: Right click-> copy css path in firebug

Comment: You should learn css.. this is very basic part. Go through w3schools.com but don't get stick to it. Once you understand basic concepts move to MDN site.

Comment: @metareviewr, doing that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#relationshipsTree>ul>li>div>span{
    color: green;
}
```

Right Click copy css path when clicking on an element in firebug will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: the problem here is that you're selecting the first-child. I want to select all parent nodes...

Comment: Edited. that should do it.